# NHibernate QueryOver and MYSQL

Tags: mysql, nhibernate, datagridview, queryover

Hi I need help with making QueryOver in NHibernate from MYSQL. MYSQL code looks like this

```
select lietadlo.id,lietadlo.volne,spolocnost.name,typ.name,typ.miest from lietadlo
join spolocnost on spolocnost.id = lietadlo.spolocnostt_id
join typ on typ.id = lietadlo.typp_id
where spolocnost.pocetlietadiel > 2
```

And then how can i write it in Data Grid View ?

Edit: So I have done so far this and try it(works good)

```
ISessionFactory factory =
new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration().Configure().BuildSessionFactory();
ISession session = null;
session = factory.OpenSession();

Lietadlo f = null;
Spolocnost t = null;
Typ r = null;

dgv.DataSource = session.QueryOver<Lietadlo>(() => f)
.JoinAlias(() => f.Spolocnostt_Id,() => t)
.JoinAlias(() => f.Typp_Id, ()=> r)
.Where(() => t.Pocetlietadiel > 2)
.And(() => r.Name == "Boeing-747")
.List<Lietadlo>()
.ToList<Lietadlo>();
```

But still in DataGridView I get only columns from Lietadlo and I want from Lietadlo only id(int),volne(int) and from Spolocnost name(string) and from Typ name(string) and miest(int).

Comment: Well, you should show us more. What have you already done? Because once, you will have objects Aeroplane, Company, AircraftType... and their mapping, the `QueryOver` construction will be really easy!

Comment: Ok I have objects, I also have mappings and I already try to do some QueryOver which actually works pretty nice but i have a problem with viewing it in datagrid view. I only see columns from table Aeroplane.

Comment: Ok, could you show what you've got so far? ;) That will help someone here to find out what is wrong. (e.g. missing JoinAlias, to load reference properties)... Show us the `QueryOver`, describe what is missing *(maybe some mapping, if it won't be clear)*...

Comment: I update it and if mapping will help I can also post them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd expect, that this is one way binding (just for reading). In this scenario you could profit from Projections. see more here [16.6. Projections](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover-projections)

You can create some DTO Object for your grid and similar to documentation:

```
CatSummary summaryDto = null;
IList<CatSummary> catReport =
    session.QueryOver<Cat>()
        .SelectList(list => list
            .SelectGroup(c => c.Name).WithAlias(() => summaryDto.Name)
            .SelectAvg(c => c.Age).WithAlias(() => summaryDto.AverageAge))
        .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<CatSummary>())
        .List<CatSummary>();
```

You should be able to do it like this *(I cannot check it right now, but it should be clear)*

```
LietadloDTO lietadloDTO = null;
dgv.DataSource = session
  .QueryOver<Lietadlo>(() => f)
  .JoinAlias(() => f.Spolocnostt_Id,() => t)
  .JoinAlias(() => f.Typp_Id, ()=> r)
  .Where(() => t.Pocetlietadiel > 2)
  .And(() => r.Name == "Boeing-747")
  .SelectList(list => list
    .Select(f => f.Id).WithAlias(() => lietadloDTO.Id)
    .Select(t => t.Name).WithAlias(() => lietadloDTO.Name)
    ...
    )
  .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<LietadloDTO>())
  .List<LietadloDTO>()
  .ToList<LietadloDTO>();
```

So, in this case, you will force NHibernate to create Projection (only 1 SELECT clause) and return all needed data at once

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I get error in .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<LietadloSumary>()) like  The name 'Transformers' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Not sure what do you mean... do you reference correct NHibernate namespace? e.g. `.TransformUsing(NHibernate.Transform.Transformers.AliasToBean<LietadloSumary>()` or `using NHibernate.Transform;`. I guess this should solve that at all ;)

Comment: Great to see that ;) NHibernate is powerful tool, even with a bit challenging learning curve ;) Tak hodně štěšstí! Jo a myslím, že ten -1 jsi dostal za ten design. Není dobrý vidět DataSource a NHibernate vedle sebe... chyběj Ti tam vrstvy... a tak. ale já Ti dávám zase +1 za snahu ;)