# Fluent Nhibernate - Join query with group by

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, queryover

I'm having trouble executing a join query in NHibernate.
I have the following tables :

```
BOOKS:
ID, NAME, BOOK_TYPE, AUTHOR_ID

AUTHORS:
ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, BIRTH_DATE
```

And I want to execute the following sql query in Fluent NHibernate:

```
SELECT AUTHORS.ID, COUNT(BOOKS.ID)
FROM AUTHORS
INNER JOIN BOOKS
ON AUTHORS.ID = BOOKS.AUTHOR_ID
GROUP BY AUTHORS.ID;
```

Class:

```
public class Book
{
     public virtual int id{get; set;}
     public virtual string Name{get; set;}
     public virtual int booktype{get; set;} 
     public virtual Author author{get; set;}
}

public class Author
{
     public virtual int id{get; set;}
     public virtual string FirstName{get; set;}
     public virtual string LastName{get; set;}
     public virtual DateTime BirthDate{get; set;}
     public virtual IList<Book> Books{get; set;}
}
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
GraphDTO graph = null;
Session.QueryOver<Book>()
.SelectList(list => list
.SelectGroup(x => x.Author.Id).WithAlias(() => graph.Id)
.SelectCount(x => x.Id).WithAlias(() => graph.BooksNum))
.TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<GraphDTO>())
.List<GraphDTO>();
```

Comment: Please update your question with your class and mapping defintion

Comment: @kayess posted the classes.

Answer (score 2):

Well, we can do it with a join and group by like this

```
Author author = null;
Book book = null;
var query = session.QueryOver<Contact>(() => author)
    .JoinQueryOver(() => author.Authors, () => book)
    .SelectList(list => list
        .SelectGroup(x => author.ID)
        // we can have more stuff from author table
        .SelectGroup(x => author.LastName)
        .SelectGroup(x => author.FirstName)
        .SelectCount(x => book.ID))
    ;

var result = query.List<object[]>();
```

But the above SQL in fact would not need JOIN, it could be just as here [Fluent Nhibernate - selecting specific column and count query with group by](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33982582/1679310)

```
session.QueryOver<Book>()
    .SelectList(list => list
        .SelectGroup(c => c.Author.ID)
        .SelectCount(c => c.ID))
    .List<object[]>();
```

Comment: The idea is perfect but you cant use the select group for that. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27527409/fluent-nhibernate-could-not-resolve-property

Comment: Have you tried my answer? I just reran that.. and it is working. Select group could be used as suggested.

Comment: Ok, so I have tried that and that works, but I dont want a list of objects, I want list of another object - lets call it GraphDTO. I edited my answer so you can see what I mean

Comment: That is standard requirement. And it could be easily solved by Transformer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26901453/1679310 or  http://stackoverflow.com/q/16496823/1679310. So you are almost there! great ;)